# Python (repeated values with append)

Tags: python, append, equation, definition

I have the following formula
Q = Square root of [(2 * C * D)/H] 
And I would like to input 100,150,180 so the output i want is 18,22,24

so my code is

```
import math
c=50
h=30
value=[]
def equation(a1,b1,c1):
    for i in (a1,b1,c1):
        value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*a1/h)))
        value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*b1/h)))
        value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*c1/h)))
        print (value)
```

when I input equation(100,150,180), why is the output following?

```
[18, 12, 24]
[18, 12, 24, 18, 12, 24]
[18, 12, 24, 18, 12, 24, 18, 12, 24]
```

How do i change the code so i get only

```
[18, 12, 24]
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are looping at all. Don't you get the right answer just by removing the `for` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop on values only to apply the same formula, in a list comprehension, also don't print the result, just return it (and print it in the caller if needed):

```
import math
c=50
h=30
def equation(a1,b1,c1):
    return [int(math.sqrt(2*c*x/h)) for x in (a1,b1,c1)]

print(equation(100,150,180))
```

result:

```
[18, 22, 24]
```

(this saves this kind of loop/where do I define my return value errors and a lot of copy/paste)

Variant with variable arguments (same calling syntax, saves argument packing & unpacking since all arguments get the same treatment):

```
def equation(*args):
    return [int(math.sqrt(2*c*x/h)) for x in args]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the `for` loop?

```
import math
c=50
h=30
def equation(a1,b1,c1):
    value=[]
    value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*a1/h)))
    value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*b1/h)))
    value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*c1/h)))
    print (value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop seems a little bit unnecessary here. If you simply want the function to return a list of the three numbers, you can use:

```
import math

c = 50
h = 30


def equation(a1, b1, c1):
    value = []
    value.append(int(math.sqrt(2 * c * a1 / h)))
    value.append(int(math.sqrt(2 * c * b1 / h)))
    value.append(int(math.sqrt(2 * c * c1 / h)))
    print(value)


equation(100, 150, 180)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `for` loop.

```
import math
c=50
h=30
value=[]
def equation(a1,b1,c1):
     value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*a1/h)))
     value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*b1/h)))
     value.append(int(math.sqrt(2*c*c1/h)))
     print (value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is what you were after:

```
import math

c = 50
h = 30

def equation(values):
    return [int(math.sqrt(2*c*i/h)) for i in values]

input = [100, 150, 180]

print(equation(input))
```

Output:

```
[18, 22, 24]
```